# How do I resize an Image using PHP while retaining resolution?

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, resolution, image-resizing

I'm wondering if there's a way to resize a batch of images using a library such as GD or ImageMagick to resize an image down while retaining its resolution?

Currently, I am starting with a very large image (roughly 3500 X 2400 @ 300ppi) when I try to resize images down (to around 1000 X 775), I get a large image in the right dimensions, but the resolution drops to 72ppi (confirmed by photoshop).

```
$im = new Imagick();
//Initial resolution of image
$im->setResolution(300,300);

$im->readImage('mypdf.pdf');
$im->adaptiveResizeImage(707,1000);
```

I've also used:

```
$image->resizeImage(707,1000, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
```

But the result ends up being pretty much the same. Thanks in advance. Any suggestions welcome.

After reading the suggestions here is how my code looks like right now

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(300,300);

$im->readImage('mypdf.pdf');
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->adaptiveResizeImage(707,1000);
$im->setResolution(300,300);
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
$originalImageFile = 'myjpg.jpg';
$im->writeImage($originalImageFile);$im->setResolution(300,300);
```

The output image has a very low quality, here is how it looks like

http://i46.tinypic.com/ehfyf8.jpg

Comment: what you call 'resolution' is in fact Pixel Density. It is obvious that if the 'physical dimensions' of the image remain the same while pixel count decreases, the pixel density will decrease too, isn't it ?

Comment: I deleted by answer because you seem to be resizing PDF files. Please clarify the post so it's clear you are talking about images inside PDFs

Comment: @SirDarius, but the physical dimensions aren't staying the same - he's scaling the image down. The pixel density should remain 300ppi, but the image is being saved at 72ppi.

Comment: then yes, the pixel density needs to be reset after the resizing operation. Also you might want to do this: $im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the answes so far!
Pekka. I'm actually cutting up PDFs and converting each page to an image.
SirDarius. I'm going to test the RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH addition.

Comment: So it works and doesn't work. Setting RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH sets the  image "pixel density" the value back to 300PPI. However, the image is STILL blurred which leads me to think that the resize function takes the image density down to 72ppi, and once you've lost the data scaling it back up doesn't help. 

N.B. I've also added the resolution change before the resize.

Comment: As a follow up to those who are interested. I think I've solved the issue (thanks to everyone's help).

The order of the operations being done matters. 
    $im->setResolution(300,300);
    $im->resizeImage(700,1000, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
    $im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
    $im->writeImage();
    $im->writeImage($originalImageFile);

Also, FILTER_LANCZOS is apparently the slowest of the filters, but produces the highest quality images.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the first comment here:

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php

In addition to setting the resolution you must also set the resolution units:

```
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I pulled the relevant part of the link into your answer. SO answers are meant to be answers, not links - links can go stale. No harm in crediting your sources though.

Comment: As mentioned, this doesn't really work because my guess is that the function to scale the image causes a loss in pixel density.

Comment: Ok here is an image showing what the problem, is, I'm using ->setImageUnits, http://i46.tinypic.com/ehfyf8.jpg this is how my code looks like right now http://pastebin.com/wfaeSv2b

Comment: @CharlieM, try saving it in a non-lossy format like PNG. Or maybe set the resolution units, then set the resolution, then read the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling setResolution again after you resize the image before you save it to disk.  Also, see the notes about Density here: [ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#density).